# Mongodb push to array

Tags: mongodb

Hey I have this collection surveysFilled:

```
{       

   repliesByQuestion: [
         {
            repliesByDeprtmrnt: [
                  [1,233,4],
                  [1,233,4],
                  [1,233,4]
             ]
          }
 }
```

in need to push to the first array inside repliesByDeprtmrnt how can i do it

Comment: Try `db.colname.update({ _id: someid },{ $push: {'repliesByQuestion.0.repliesByDeprtmrnt": [1,345,4] } }
)`

Comment: thank you its working !!!!!!!!!!!